# Is there a way to prove that God’s foreknowledge is incompatible with genuine human freedom?

Tags: comparative-christianity, free-will, omniscience, omnipotence, foreknowledge

Here are two statements that I have always considered self-evident:

> God’s total foreknowledge is not compatible with genuine human freedom.
>
> God is with us at all times but does not know in advance what we will think or do.

Having stated my “Axioms of God’s Foreknowledge vs. Human Freedom”, I have gradually realized that what is for me self evident, and therefore axiomatic, is not so for many Christians. Anyway, I have come to realize that it is necessary to demonstrate what to me is obvious, either directly, or by disproving the opposite, viz. the position that is referred to as "compatibilism":

> [**Compatibilism**] God’s total foreknowledge is compatible with genuine human freedom (see e.g. [Divine Foreknowledge and Human Freedom Are Compatible](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2216201?seq=1) @ jstor.org)

**Is there a way to prove that God’s foreknowledge is incompatible with genuine human freedom? If so, can someone provide an Answer with that proof?**

**P.S.** While I am interested to receive "[an overview of all Christian positions](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/870/how-should-i-ask-overview-questions-on-one-matter-from-all-of-the-christian-spe)", **the priority is for a logically valid answer to the Question**.

Comment: Compatibilism is a belief that determinism and free will are compatible. Foreknowledge isn't the same as determinism. Foreknowledge is simply *knowing* in advance what will happen, whereas determinism implies *controlling* what will happen.

Comment: @SamuelBradshaw Interesting discussion about a Question that has been declared "off-topic". Anyway, I see the problem in the terms described at SEP > [Foreknowledge and Free Will](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/free-will-foreknowledge/), including possible objections of "[modal fallacy](https://www.sfu.ca/~swartz/modal_fallacy.htm)".

Comment: I cannot answer this as an overview is requested.  The internet Encyclopedia of Philosophy has this entry explaining how foreknowledge does not eradicate freedom:  https://iep.utm.edu/foreknow/  The entry is lengthy and not simplistic.  The bible states, without any limitations or qualifiers, that God knows the end from the beginning (Isaiah 46:10) and it seems obvious and axiomatic that God must foreknow all the choices that lend themselves to producing whatever future event He has predicted.  Otherwise He was just hoping Abraham would believe, Mary would obey, Jesus would win, etc.

Comment: @MaikeBorden I edited the question, I believe, in agreement with the reasons given to me by SE for closing it and, perhaps, reopening it. Then it was **heavily** modified in the sense that you have noticed, in particular transforming the mention of the "overview" , from the way I had tentatively phrased it (**P.S.** I am interested to receive "[an overview of all Christian positions](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/870/how-should-i-ask-overview-questions-on-one-matter-from-all-of-the-christian-spe)"), to an integral part of the question. So I will have to edit it again.

Comment: I don't know why you'd be upset by my edit, I didn't change anything substantive. It's best to put the fact that this is an overview question up front because it's very easy to overlook a sentence in a question. I've done it myself many times and seen others do it even more. So directly asking in the question title for an overview is strongly recommended.

Comment: @curiousdannii I have just edited the question. If Maike Borden says that, in consequence of your edit, he "cannot answer", this is not right. The key is that mine is a **question**, that "an overview of all Christian positions" is **only an option** and that I am looking for a **logically valid** Answer.

Comment: @MikeBorden (sorry for misspelling your name, before), now that I have re-edited the Question (and I hope it's going to stay like that ...). I hope you will give your Answer. I am well aware of the IEP article [Foreknowledge and Free Will](https://iep.utm.edu/foreknow/) by Norman Swartz, professor emeritus of philosophy, Simon Fraser University. I believe I have found a weekness in his argument against Maimonides, which, while true in general, does not work in the special case of an Omnipotent and Omiscient God. Once I have revised my argument, I may post it as my Answer to my Question.

Comment: @Migeul That's not how this site works. You can't ask for either a logical answer or an overview. And actually you can't ask for a "logical" answer at all. You either direct the question to one denomination, or to all of them. If you want an answer from logic alone, then the [philosophy.se] site is the place to go. If you haven't seen it, [What types of questions can I ask on this site?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3409/6071)

Comment: If it is true that the existence of God is non-disprovable doesn't it follow that whatever degree of foreknowledge He actually has (if He actually exists) is also non-disprovable?  For those who hold to His self revelation in Scripture that same Scripture is our only recourse.  It feels as though we sometimes are searching for the God who obeys our intellects but, of Himself, He says that He knows the end from the beginning.  Why do we have to be intellectually satisfied *before* we can believe Him?

Comment: _Why do we have to be intellectually satisfied_ before _we can believe Him?_ Well, talking about "Scripture is our only recourse", I am still battling with the Canaanite Genocide (Deuteronomy and Joshua) and Saul Amalekite Genocide, whether they 1) are real 2) if they are real, whether they were really done at YHWH's bidding.

Comment: @MikeBorden I was grossly mistaken: my Question never stood a chance: the only way for it to survive was to ask for "opinions"! :(

Comment: I understand.  Those are some difficult things to assimilate.  May the Holy Spirit, in the name of the Lord Jesus, guide you into all truth.

Comment: @MigueldeServet Do you struggle similarly with the Flood where all but 8 people were destroyed?

Comment: @Mike No, a long time ago I have decided to consider Genesis, up to the call of Abram, mythical/figurative. Who do you understand to be "the sons of God [who] saw that the daughters of humankind were beautiful [and] took wives for themselves from any they chose"?

Comment: @MigueldeServet I have yet to land somewhere comfortable on they and the Nephilim.

Answer (score 1):

**Open Theists** say that God's knowledge of the future is incompatible with libertarian notion of human freedom.  Their solution is to limit God's omniscience so God does not know the future.

Their position is discussed in the IEP entry [Open Theism](https://iep.utm.edu/o-theism/), as well as in a 2001 article by theologian John Frame [Open Theism and Divine Foreknowledge](https://frame-poythress.org/open-theism-and-divine-foreknowledge/).  *Wikipedia* also has a good article on [Open Theism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_theism) which includes:

- Comparison with Reformed theism
- Varieties of open theists
- A large list of scholars since 1980
- A nice table of representative books by both sides

In this scheme, your 2 axiomatic statements can remain true (highlighted in the quote from John Frame's article below) and you will get your libertarian style free will:

> A free act in the libertarian sense⁸ is an act that is utterly uncaused, undetermined. It is not caused by God, nor by anything in creation, nor even by the desires and dispositions of the one who performs the act. Such causes may “influence” or “incline” us to a certain choice, but they never determine a choice, if that choice is free in the libertarian sense. At the moment of choice, on this view, we are always equally able to choose or not to choose a particular alternative.⁹ For this reason, libertarian freedom is sometimes called “liberty of indifference,” for up to the very moment of choice nothing is settled; the will is indifferent.¹⁰
>
> Now if people are free in the libertarian sense, then human decisions are radically unpredictable. **Even God cannot know them in advance.** If in 1930 God knew that I would be writing this article in 2000, then I would not be writing it freely. I could not avoid writing it. So if my writing is a free choice in the libertarian sense, **even God cannot have been certain of it in advance**. Libertarian freedom excludes the classical view of God’s foreknowledge.¹¹
>
> On this view, the future is of such a nature that it cannot be known exhaustively. So open theists claim that on their view God is indeed omniscient, in the sense that he knows everything that can be known. That he lacks exhaustive knowledge of the future is no more of a limitation than his inability to make a square circle. Just as his omnipotence enables him to do everything that can be done, so his omniscience enables him to know everything that can be known. That includes knowledge of the past and present, but not the future, so open theists name their view presentism.¹²
>
> For open theists, therefore, libertarian freedom is a fundamental premise, a standard by which all other theological statements are judged. **Typically, open theists do not argue the case (such as there is) for libertarian freedom; rather, they assume it.** ¹³ It is their presupposition. So God cannot have exhaustive knowledge of the future. Pinnock says,
>
> > However, omniscience need not mean exhaustive foreknowledge of all future events. **If that were its meaning, the future would be fixed and determined, much as is the past. Total knowledge of the future would imply a fixity of events. Nothing in the future would need to be decided. It also would imply that human freedom is an illusion, that we make no difference and are not responsible.** ¹⁴
>
> **He is saying that God cannot know the future exhaustively, because if he did we would not have libertarian freedom.**

All 3 articles discuss scriptural support cited by their proponents, but

- there is **big cost**: i.e. no guarantee that everything will work out as God wants in the end, God's glory is diminished (see section 4 of the IEP article)
- there is **incoherency** when taking the full scriptural evidence into account (see the last 2 sections of John Frame's article: 'Divine Ignorance in Scripture?' and 'God’s Exhaustive Knowledge of the Future').

Comment: Thank you for your links and quotations. As for your "but" at the end: **(1)** God's plan will prevail, but there will be casualties on the way; your undestanding of the consequences of Open Theism ("God's glory is diminished") are a biased misreading of the paragraph. **(2)** Where would you find the alleged "incoherency"?

Comment: @MigueldeServet **(1)** Section 4 says that "If Open Theism is true, then there is **no guarantee that everything will work out as God wants in the end**. Open Theists may trust and hope in God’s wisdom and power, but they recognize that there are limitations on what God can effect if we stubbornly refuse to aid Him." **How is it biased?**  As for "God's glory is diminished", I think it depends on how one defines God's glory. I actually agree with the author about **more** glory if we have greater role in our salvation (paragraph 12) but we can argue God receives **less** glory in paragraph 5.

Comment: @MigueldeServet About **(2)** there are several incoherency, spelled out in paragraph 4 of "God's Exhaustive Knowledge of the Future" : "the second kind of prophecy ... ought to be troubling to open theists..."  then later John Frame cites many verses implying how there are other prophecies that "anticipate countless free decisions of human beings, long before any had the opportunity to form their own character", and the final 2 paragraphs about God's "knowledge that include exhaustive knowledge of the **future**" (emphasis mine).  To me (I agree, it's subjective), it's part of God's glory.

Comment: Grateful, **(1)** In §4 of the IEP article it is NOT affirmed that "God's glory is diminished", BUT it is **asked**, "To what extent is God’s glory diminished etc.?" You even say that you "agree with the author". I do not know what you refer to by "paragraph 12" and "paragraph 5" [continues]

Comment: @MigueldeServet Paragraph 12 is when the author argue against the opponent's saying "God's glory is diminished" in regard to salvation.  Paragraph 5 is when the author discusses how God deals with human gratuitous evil.  He said: "If instead one cannot imagine that God would allow us to perform such horrible acts ... without there being some very great good that they serve, then one is likely to put one’s faith in the mysterious but certain goodness of God’s meticulous governance of creation." which **to me is another aspect of God's glory diminished because of Open Theism**.

Comment: @MigueldeServet As I said, defining God's glory is subjective.  What I meant in my answer is Section 4 includes material pointing to weaknesses in Open Theism vis a vis God's glory.  The article is very well written, by the way, fair to both sides.  I agree with him on paragraph 12, but opt for the 2nd perspective on paragraph 5, which I'm sure the opponents of Open Theism also link to diminished glory.

Comment: Grateful [continued] **(2)** It all depends how to understand the expression "Exhaustive Knowledge of the Future", and whether or not God would enjoy it.

Comment: @MigueldeServet "*whether or not God would enjoy it*".  How are we supposed to know?  We are not God.  We are just trying to discern whether God knows the future based on proper interpretation of Scripture.  Isn't that what theology is?  I trust John Frame's handling of Scripture in that paper, so I agree with his conclusion that Open Theism doesn't deal with the **full** scriptural evidence, hence the "incoherence"

Comment: Grateful **First**, let’s cut to the chase, shall we? The point of contention is [free will](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_will_in_theology) (speaking of “libertarian” free will is simply redundant or tendentious), how the views of “[Open theism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_theism)” differ from those of traditional “[Classical theism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_theism)”, and whether **inherent** rather than **total** omniscience of God is in better agreement with the evidence of Scripture. [continues]

Comment: [continued] **Second**, the way you referred to "incoherency" in your Answer, and then in your comment, didn't make at all clear whether your were referring to the "incoherency" of John Frame's paper or of Open Theism itself. Now you are openly pointing at the latter. I don't agree that John Frame provides satisfactory evidence whereby "Open Theism doesn't deal with the full scriptural evidence". BTW, I simply do not attribute any authority to the _Westminster Confession of Faith_, or other similar documents.

Answer (score 0):

Logic requires definitions.
In particular, does "omniscient" mean "knows everything" or "is capable of knowing everything"?

If you want the former, you might also wonder why, if God is omnipotent, he hasn't *done* everything.
The obvious answer is that omnipotence must mean the latter kind of definition.

Similarly, God's ability to know everything doesn't mean that he *does* know everything.

I live near Maple Hills Creek.
I know that its water will flow into the Grand River, and thence into Lake Ontario, and eventually into the Atlantic Ocean.

I know this in general, but am incapable of knowing it with absolute certainty (perhaps Yellowstone will explode tonight and mess everything up), nor am I capable of knowing whether any specific individual water molecule will evaporate before it reaches the ocean.

But most of the time, knowing the big picture is enough, the details usually don't matter.

God knows with absolute certainty how history will flow.
But, with a few exceptions, he has no need to know how an individual person will behave within that flow of history.
Even with specific individuals that are predestined to play a role in his plan, it's sufficient to occasionally nudge them back onto the right track without knowing every little detail of what they are going to do.

God might be capable of knowing everything, but why would he bother?

---

As another analogy, suppose you record a video of a child playing.
Later, when you view it, you will know for sure what will happen, but that in no way means that the child didn't use free will to decide what to do; you simply know what that decision will be.

Comment: Ray, the understanding of "omniscient" as "capable of knowing everything" rather than "knows everything" (and similarly for "omnipotent") is fundamental. OTOH, the "another analogy" at the end is totally botched and inconsistent with your previous "why would he bother?". If God saw the future as the past, like an unchangeable film, then we would be mere robots, or (to use a more Platonic image), mere shadows.

Comment: @MigueldeServet I know that yesterday I freely chose a can of cold Spaghetio's for lunch.  I see that choice in the past, like an unchangeable film.  Was I a mere robot yesterday or a shadow on account of my knowledge today?  Of course not.  This applies in the other direction as well, the only difference is that we cannot see into the future.  God can and we must shake off the need to transfer our limitations onto Him.

Comment: Did God foreknow that Adam would choose poorly?

Comment: Mike, I cannot think of a sadder choice than "a can of cold Spaghetio's for lunch" :(

Comment: _Did God foreknow that Adam would choose poorly?_ Did He? If He did, what is your comment?